# Bigcartel neat theme

Tags: css, themes, neat, bigcartel

I am currently working on customising the welcome page for my Bigcartel site.

I am using the Neat theme and would like to remove the grid filter that appears over the slideshow to appear clean.

I was wondering if it's possible in Big Cartel and what was the process to follow?

I've tried this so far..

```
.slideshow div.featured_holder {
  background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After fiddling around with the CSS, I was able to remove the texture and darkening of the image with these two changes.

First, find this in your CSS:

```
.flickity-viewport:after {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-image: url("{{ 'overlay_pattern.png' | theme_image_url }}");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 4px;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Now, you're going to want to remove this line entirely to remove the textured overlay:

```
background-image: url("{{ 'overlay_pattern.png' | theme_image_url }}");
```

To remove the image darkening, simply change this:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
```

To this:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Your slideshow images should appear normal with those two changes.